# Is it possible to import an OBJ containing a number of splines (no geometry) and render them with Three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have a relatively complex object comprised of a bunch of splines. I'm extremely new to WebGL and Three.js and was wondering if importing a bunch of splines into Three.js and rendering those using some sort of Cel / Toon shading is something I can do?

I've tried using the threejs.org/editor and importing the splines OBJ definitely didn't work.

I do know about the ObjLoader so loading the file is not the problem. The problem is getting the splines rendered.

[image: Here's what I'd like to render]

Comment: the obj loader only loads triangles. it knows nothing about splines. so you need to convert your object to an .obj format model and then use the loader.

Comment: @gaitat Thanks for the comment. Okay I get it. ObjLoader would only load polygons. What format should I convert the .obj to than? I know I can convert .obj to .json...? Is that what you mean by "convert yur object to an obj format model? Cheers!

Comment: no I mean you need to polygonalize your model that is created by splines and then export it to the OBJ format (or which other format you prefer)

Comment: Why does he have to load polygons if e wants to render splines? Not sure which format holds the splines, nor if there is an importer to do it, but if you can write your splines into a json it would be trivial to parse it. An array of floats or arrays of floats could hold a polygonal line.